# Find Out How Many Times User Logged Out

Tags: php, session

I have a system already built in which users get automatically logged out after a certain period of time. What I'm trying to do is find out how many times a specific user was logged out.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What stops you from couting up when you log a user out?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but here goes anyway:

You said you have a database backing you up. Use it.
Create a field stating `LastActivity`, which you update each time the person does something on your website. If the `LastActivity` has been too long ago, disconnect the user from the website (by killing the session). At the same time, you can update some sort of field, which counts how often that user has been 'forced to log out'.

Answer (score 0):

Just count how many times the user log in... It's exactly the same, no?

Comment: Thanks for answers it is really quick. What i mean is i have code for time out. if user stays inactive like 100 secs. He/she is automatically logged out. I can have different users. And i want to keep track of the amount of timeout for each users seperately. When i read answer i understand something like that. If it is true please let me know. i have a table something like username and password. Add one more cloumn like amount of timeout. And When one of user timeout increase number + 1 or something like that. can i get it right. Thanks.